# Best Rails Tagging Plugin/Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

what plugin or gem do you recommened for tagging?
There are many of them, acts_as_taggable, acts_as_taggable_on_steroids, acts_as_taggable_on,...

What do you say?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's a [good list of tagging plugins](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_tagging.html) ordered by ranking.

Comment: The site is temporary unavailable.

Comment: This site is reachable again.

Answer (score 9):

Just went through this.

1. Started with `is_taggable` because I liked having something simple
2. Then I need to find tagged items like `Website.tagged_with("sports")` which it didn't support so I switched to `acts_as_taggable_on`, the most popular one on github
3. It worked well for a while, but it's `tagged_with` function had bugs.  When searching for a non-existent tag it returned all results instead of zero.  So I finally switched to `acts_as_taggable_on_steroids` and all is good now.  Whew!

Summary: my current vote it for [`acts_as_taggable_on_steroids`](http://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids/)

Comment: Looks like acts_as_taggable_on fixed the issue mentioned above:
http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/closed/#issue/20

Answer (score 6):

Updating this question because it's pretty high in the google results.  After looking around at the links in these answers, we settled on `acts-as-taggable-on` https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Works with Rails 3 (though as I type this, has an issue with 3.0.10).  Easy enough to use.  Active development.  Support for tag context which I'm sure we're going to want soon.

Answer (score 1):

My favourites is `acts_as_taggable_on_steroids`, it's more recent and updated version of the classic `acts_as_taggable`.

Comment: But isn't acts_as_taggable_on the most recent one?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to figure this out this morning, and chose acts_as_taggable_redux.  It has built in support for tag clouds, and all the other features I needed.  The most compelling point was that the last update was in October 2009, while the others look like they haven't been touched in a while.